# Can array bounds checking be performed statically?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

Can array bounds checking be performed statically? 
I think it can be done only with static arrays (compiler knows size) and not dynamic arrays (compiler doesn't know size).

EDIT: Initial question about C and Java and their tradeoffs (speed vs efficiency) is answered and seemed unclear too, so removed.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly is your question? What do you mean with bounds checking? If you refer to the size of an array, you should read up on the basics of Java.

Comment: Yes, checking if the index is within the bounds of the array.

Comment: Then you should read some tutorials about Java.

Comment: I couldn't find a good tutorial about this. Any links to a good one?

Comment: That i do not buy. Every basic tutorial covers arrays and its properties. Just google "Java tutorial" and take the Oracle one.

Answer (score 2):

C tends to value speed above everything else, so bounds checking isn't part of the language.  In the general case, it cannot be done for all code statically, so there will be a runtime cost that performance critical applications do not wish to pay.

*Gcc* does not support inserting code to do bounds checking.  Someone has [added code](https://gcc.gnu.org/extensions.html) to do this, but it hasn't been added into the official sources.

Comment: Thanks. When you say "it cannot be done for all code statically": just to clarify, it could do it for a static array but not a dynamic array? Or am I getting it all mixed up?

Comment: It is harder but not impossible to do with a dynamic array, since the size of the array would need to be determined using static code analysis techniques.  This involves looking at different code paths, function calls, loops, etc.  Not easy, and the analysis can't always predict values of variables or the size of dynamic arrays.